Is it possible to use the same `GoRoute` as item of `GoRouter`'s routes and the item of `ShellRoute`'s routes?
I have a GoRouter:
GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/login',
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/dashboard',
        ),
        // ... other routes
      ]
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      path: '/dashboard',
    ),
    // ... other routes
  ],
)

As you may notice I use the same route /dashboard (and similar routes) in different places. The fact is I can redirect to similar route either from BottomNavigationBar or Drawer. When I go to dashboard from the Drawer I need to have a back button on AppBar so I use go.push() to place the route above the ScaffoldWithNavigation's current selected one.
The question is if it is possible to use the same GoRoute (the same path) in different route sets? Or should I use different route paths?

I am using that when I have navigation for mobile devices, but I want to separate the navigation for the web. In my observation, it depends on my routing setup. But I used that way to separate those platforms' routing. I have yet no idea if my setup was good or not.

@DevQt it would be good to see the working exampe. I could not achieve the correct work without changing paths for different routes? Could you please to create a simple gist to see how did you do?

I tried to reanalyze your issue, and I realized that my answer seems unlikely to resolve it. So, I will reevaluate my answer to address the related issue. You can comment on it to see if it provides some insights.

I decided to demonstrate the program I was talking about for you to see that it is possible to have that GoRouter hierarchy.

I've decided to provide this answer as per BambinoUA's request.
Here's the relevant code snippet for demonstration:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class GoRouterMobile {
  static CustomTransitionPage noTransition(
    GoRouterState state,
    Widget page,
  ) {
    return CustomTransitionPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      child: page,
      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
          child,
    );
  }
}

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => GoRouterMobile.noTransition(
        state,
        Home(),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'page1', // for web browser purposes
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => GoRouterMobile.noTransition(
            state,
            Page1(),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'page2', // for web browser purposes
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => GoRouterMobile.noTransition(
                state,
                Page2(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page1', // for mobile app purposes
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => GoRouterMobile.noTransition(
        state,
        Page1(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page2', // for mobile app purposes
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => GoRouterMobile.noTransition(
        state,
        Page2(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('Home'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                kIsWeb
                    ? context.go('///page1')
                    : GoRouter.of(context).push(Uri(path: '/page1').toString());
              },
              child: Text('Go to Page 1'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (GoRouter.of(context).canPop()) {
              GoRouter.of(context).pop();
            }
          },
          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_back),
        ),
        title: Text('Page 1'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('Page 1'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                kIsWeb
                    ? context.go('///page1/page2')
                    : GoRouter.of(context)
                        .push(Uri(path: '/page2').toString());
              },
              child: Text('Go to Page 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
      dismissOnCapturedTaps: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (GoRouter.of(context).canPop()) {
                GoRouter.of(context).pop();
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_back),
          ),
          title: Text('Page 2'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text('Page 2'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.go('/'); // to avoid having a page stack in the page cycle
                },
                child: Text('Go to Home'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code was originally dedicated solely to the mobile app, but I've also decided to include the web behavior of the go_router implementation.
Here's the web runtime:

And here's the mobile runtime:

Code snippet explanation: As you can see from the given code snippet, the GoRouter's hierarchy introduces the same path in different route sets.
I know it is slightly different from your GoRouter code snippet case example, but you can use it as a reference for navigation using context.go for the web (but depending on the case [e.g., use context.go instead of GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacement]) and GoRouter.of(context).push for mobile.
I hope it helps!
